# manually data aggregation by MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-streams, aggregation, rocksdb

we need to aggregate data over same keys. already, we were using MongoDB to aggregate data. pipeline was like below:

Kafka --> mongoDB

for every record from Kafka we query Mongo to find out is there that key or not. if there is, we read it and sum Kafka record with That and then save it. we aggregate data over 2 weeks and every Mongo record delete after that ( ttl is 2 week).

recently we try to use KafkaStream instead of Mongo. but we are facing many issues like stateStore restoration ( about 100G for 2 weeks, and o) , data backup, setting ttl on stateStore ...
our kafka stream thread get  shutdown periodically)
also in parallel and for comparison we are aggregating data using reactive Mongo  and it seems speed of aggregating data is not very different.

my question is : is there any point in using kafka-stream instead of mongo in this situation?

Comment: Difficult to follow what you are asking. But i dont think kafka is required here

Comment: what is unclear? @AsadAwadia